# One of two request make my server crash. Someone know? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

The first request make my server crash (The CPU go to 100%)

```
SELECT s.idSinistre
FROM test_apc_sinistres s 
INNER JOIN apc_correspondances c ON c.idLiaison = s.idSinistre AND c.refCategorie = '69.1'
INNER JOIN apc_procedures_taches_sinistres p ON s.idSinistre = p.idSinistre 
INNER JOIN apc_contacts co ON s.idAdb = co.idContact
INNER JOIN apc_parametres_adb pa ON pa.idAdb = co.idContact
WHERE s.refStatut = '62.2' 
GROUP BY s.idSinistre;

select co.Nom, s.idSinistre, count(c.idMessage) as nbMEssage, count(p.id) as nbProc
from test_apc_sinistres s 
inner join apc_correspondances c on c.idLiaison = s.idSinistre and c.refCategorie = '69.1'
inner join apc_procedures_taches_sinistres p on s.idSinistre = p.idSinistre
inner join apc_contacts co on s.idAdb = co.idContact
inner join apc_parametres_adb pa on pa.idAdb = co.idContact
where s.refStatut = '62.2'
group by s.idSinistre;
```

The only difference between this two is the data i select. Someone already have this issue?

Comment: crash <> 100% cpu

Comment: Query 2 is invalid. Should raise an error.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the server not crash but the website is off because the database does not respond. 
Why the query 2 is invalid? because it's the only one who work

Answer (score 0):

Just re-check your columns one by one and you'll see that you are doing aggregates on all except one column.